# Error al desencriptar (RSA) Java

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que encripta y desencripta, pero al desencriptar me da el error BadPaddingException: Decryption error. Hay dos métodos que encriptan y desencriptan al final del código, el error me da a la hora de desencriptar, en la linea String mensajeDescifrado = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(texto)), "UTF-8");

Este es mi código (he omitido código innecesario).
Gracias.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {        
    // Generamos el keygen
    System.out.println("Obteniendo generador de claves con cifrado RSA");
    KeyPairGenerator keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    // Generamos el par de claves
    System.out.println("Generando par de claves");
    // Generamos el cipher.
    KeyPair parejaClaves = keygen.generateKeyPair();
    System.out.println("Obteniendo objeto Cipher con cifrado RSA");
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");                  
}

/**
 * Función que cifra.
 * Recibe el texto leído del fichero y lo devuelve cifrado.
 */
public static String CifrarFichero(String texto, Cipher cipher, KeyPair claves) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    System.out.println("Configurando Cipher");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, claves.getPrivate());
    System.out.println("Cifrando mensaje");
    // Ciframos el mensaje.
    String mensajeCifrado = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(texto.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    System.out.println("Cifrado");
    // Devolvemos el mensaje.
    return mensajeCifrado;
}

/**
 * Función que descifra 
 */
public static String DescifrarFichero(String texto, Cipher cipher, KeyPair claves) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{        
    System.out.println("Configurando Cipher");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, claves.getPublic());
    // Desciframos el mensaje.
    System.out.println("Descifrando mensaje");
    String mensajeDescifrado = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(texto)), "UTF-8");
    // Devolvemos el mensaje descifrado.
    return mensajeDescifrado;
}
```

}

Comment: Se agradece que te esfuerces en limpiar el código que presentas, pero me parece que te has pasado: desde el `main` no hay llamadas a `CifrarFichero` ni `DescifrarFichero`. Pero por lo demás la pregunta está bastante bien.

Comment: Es que el programa va más allá; se supone que lee el contenido de un fichero y lo cifra creando otro fichero, y al revés también, pero el problema está en el cifrado, por eso no he incluído la parta de ficheros ya que esa parte funciona bien.

Comment: Haz un [mcve]; en este caso es muy sencillo. Desde el `main` llamas a `CifrarFichero` con un texto cualquiera metido "a mano", y luego llamas a `DescifrarFichero` con el valor obtenido.

Comment: Lo he probado, pero me da el error que he escrito arriba.